# Wubi For Fedora?

Tags: fedora, wubi

Ubuntu has the ability to install within Windows via [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer). Is the same thing possible with Fedora?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible, at least not yet anyway.